# Ошибка запуска скрипта bitrix в XAMPP

Tags: php, битрикс, xampp

Стала устанавливать на локалку bitrix через xampp (bitrix выдал ошибку что php плохой нужен новее. Пришлось полностью переустанавливать xampp (замена файлов php ни к чему хорошему не привела). Теперь при открывании файла в браузере скрипт не запускается, а пишет вот такой длинующий текст без запуска. Нигде не могу найти информацию, что не так с настройками xampp?

[image: ошибка запуска phph файла]

Comment: А какая версия PHP? Должна быть не ниже 5.6.

Comment: Такая ошибка означает, что PHP не подвязался к апачу. К тому же в сообщениях написана ошибка, которую вам нужно проверить. А на какой ОС у Вас XAMPP уже несколько лет не видел чтобы им пользовались

Comment: Php встроенный 7 с копейками. А чем посоветуете пользоваться? Мне без разницы) лишь бы на локалке работали сайты

Comment: При этом у меня был старый xampp с php 5.3 и все норм было, но Битрикс нужен минимум 5.6, поэтому пришлось все переустанавливать

Comment: я для локалки на винде рекомендую OpenServer. Для Linux использоваться штатный LAMP-стек. Для MacOS MAMP. Проблем никогда не возникало. Также можно использовать виртуальную машину с установленным на ней веб-окружением от битрикса на базе CentOS.

Comment: Спасибо за совет! OpenServer - качала с родного сайта, очень медленно процесс шел, через торрент пришлось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Как уже писали - проверьте специальным скриптом bitrix_server_test.php настройки php, apache, mysql.
2. По скрину, у вас на 99% проблема в php.ini short_open_tag=off, а нужно short_open_tag=on.
3. Советы типа поставь окружение битрикс, так проще работать, лучше не воспринимать. Поймете в какую сторону копать и уже не будет таких проблем с развертыванием на локальном сервере или на боевом.

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте соответствует ли веб-сервер требованиям CMS [специальным скриптом от вендора](https://www.1c-bitrix.ru/download/scripts/bitrix_server_test.php). Там при работе если есть несоответствия, то будут рекомендации что сделать с настройками php или mysql чтобы все заработало (где выключить Safe mode и т.д.).

Answer (score 0):

для битрикса вместо XAMPP следует юзать
[своё собственное веб-окружение](https://www.1c-bitrix.ru/products/env/) В состав входит все, что нужно
Если нужно развернуть виртуалку, помогут [образа для популярных виртуалок](https://www.1c-bitrix.ru/products/vmbitrix/) от самого битрикса

Comment: Как вариант, хотела попробовать разные CMS с "одного" места. попробую OpenServer.